# Is there an S3 bucket name equivalent to www.example.com?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Say if I need to use a bucket name in a test but didn't want it to be a real bucket accidentally.

For instance, some reserved bucket names in the same vein as https://www.iana.org/domains/reserved

Comment: I'm not aware of any reserved bucket name like that, though I use an invalid name like `.EXAMPLE.` when I need something like this.

Comment: Depends on what you want to try - the bucket named "example" certainly is a valid bucket, it simply belongs to someone else already and you do not have access to it.